# Change color of line with ball movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I had to move a circle on line

```
ctx1.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
```

I want to change the color of line from grey to red with the movement of ball. I was trying this

```
function rancolour() 
{ 
   var red = Math.floor(Math.random() *255); 
   var green = Math.floor(Math.random() *255); 
   var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
   ctx1.color = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')'; 
}
```

Can any I help?? Both are canvas element.

Comment: You have not given a clear description of what you're trying to do

Comment: Hi, I want to move a ball on line x=200, I want to add color to the line with the moment of ball, means if say initial state was grey then then ball movement adds the color to the line.. like ball is giving life to the line with colors.. where ever balls go along the line/path it adds color to it... Hope you get my problem....Raj

Comment: function draw1() { //ball code
        ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        ctx1.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
         ctx1.fill();
          ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx1.closePath();
        ctx1.fill();
         if (x > 200 || x < WIDTH)
            dx = +dy;
        if (y = 200)
            dy = +dy;

        x += dx;
        y += dy;

Comment: function draw2() {    //code for box on which I want to add colors //with ball movement...
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        //ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx2.strokeStyle = "Grey"; // line color
        ctx2.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx2.moveTo(0, 200);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 200);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 100);
        ctx2.lineTo(400, 100);
        ctx2.lineTo(400, 300);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 300);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 100);
        ctx2.lineTo(400, 100);
        ctx2.lineTo(400, 200);
        ctx2.lineTo(600, 200);
        ctx2.stroke();

Answer (score 1):

If your line starts at `(x1,y1)` and ends at `(x2,y2)`, with your current position being `(x,y)`, then you can calculate the required RGB color at every point with:

```
var percent=((x2-x)*(x2-x)+(y2-y)*(y2-y))/((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)); 
ctx1.color='rgb('+(128*(1-percent)+255*percent)+','+(128*(1-percent))+','+(128*(1-percent))+')';
```

This will change the color of your ball from grey `rgb(128,128,128)` to red `rgb(255,0,0)`.

Comment: Hi, I was trying my hands with your method, but not getting any color change... I need to change the line color not ball color...

Comment: The answer to my query is, one can't have two colors on same line of same ctx. The way I opted is to run another line with ball of another context and it will give appearance that ball is changing the line color. I don't know if its the best way to do it...